# Query for getting values from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have a table **video** with fields *videoid*, *genre(int-foreign key)*, *language(int-foreign key)* etc. I want to get the value of *genre* from **genre** table and *language* from **movie_languages** table.

The structure of tables are given below:

**video**

[image]

**genre**

[image]

**movie_languages**

[image]

How can I join these 3 tables to get the language and genre related to each videos in video table. Also when user didn't select genre/language in the form, value 0 will be inserted to the table. Will this affect the query. I am using codeingiter and I tried with the following query and is not working.

```
$this->db->select('video.*,movie_languages.language,genre.genre');    
$this->db->join('genre', 'video.genre = genre.id');
$this->db->join('movie_languages', 'video.language = movie_languages.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried? : [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479079/how-to-join-three-tables-in-codeigniter?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be, you need a left join in this case

Try this

```
$query = $this->db
->select('v.*,ml.language,g.genre')
->from('video as v')
->join('movie_languages AS ml', 'v.language = ml.id', 'left outer')
->join('genre AS g', 'v.genre = g.id', 'left outer')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$this->db->select('video.*,movie_languages.language,genre.genre') 
         ->from('video')
         ->join('genre', 'video.genre = genre.id')
         ->join('movie_languages', 'video.language = movie_languages.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But this query will not show those records where genre/language are 0.

Comment: you can add where condition ->where('genre',0)

Comment: @MohitJain you need a left join in this case. Have a look at my answer