# Join three table

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Kindly Help me

i Have three tables there names is company,admin and leads .i getting all the data of leads and one record from company=user_name and one record from admin=display_name but here i am confused Coz company and admin 'ID' save in same fields ..Please Any One Help me ..Thanks

**Added From Comment:**

My Query

```
SELECT inno_admin.display_name,inno_company.Pseudo_name,inno_leads.* FROM inno_leads INNER JOIN inno_company ON inno_company.id = inno_leads.agent_id inno_admin ON inno_admin.id=inno_leads.agent_id ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: include your table structure and sample date with expected output

Comment: (My Query)
SELECT inno_admin.display_name,inno_company.Pseudo_name,inno_leads.* FROM inno_leads INNER JOIN              inno_company  ON inno_company.id = inno_leads.agent_id  inno_admin ON inno_admin.id=inno_leads.agent_id  ORDER BY ID DESC

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479079/how-to-join-three-tables-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Just add 2 where conditions.

```
$name = "any name";
$this->db->select("");// select required fields.
$this->db->join("company","join criteria");
$this->db->join("admin","join criteria");
$this->db->where("company.company_name",$name);
$this->db->where("admin.display_name",$name);
$this->db->group_by("leads.agent_id");//   <------ new line added.
$this->db->get("leads");
```

Comment: Thanks Raju ..I trying

Comment: @MurtazaSaeedkhan, sure... let me know the status.

Comment: i help from my freind they told me use foreach loop ..i fallow ur query but too confused on it..

Comment: Bro i get  record from same ID ..agent_id

Comment: join with 2 tables, add 2 where conditions. Whats confusing in that??

Comment: if you are getting multiple records for same id use, `GROUP BY` clause. `$this->db->group_by("table.column");`

Comment: Dear I Beginner in CI and first i have no idea "any Name" from my fields get any name

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what your after as question bit confusing. The code below will let you get all data.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

```
public function get_data_results() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('inno_leads', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('inno_company', 'inno_company.id = inno_leads.agent_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('inno_admin', 'inno_admin.id = inno_leads.agent_id', 'LEFT');
    // order_by id up to you but there
    $this->db->order_by('inno_leads.agent_id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        //return $query->result();
        //Or
        //return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Pass $name from controller through to model.

```
public function get_data($name) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('inno_leads', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('inno_company', 'inno_company.id = inno_leads.agent_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('inno_admin', 'inno_admin.id = inno_leads.agent_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->where("inno_company.company_name", $name);
    $this->db->where("inno_admin.display_name", $name);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Controller Sample Function

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('some_model');

   // Note this could be a uri segment also or session data.
   // $name = $this->uri->segment(2); 

    $name = 'Your Company Name'; 

    $company_info = $this->some_model->get_data($name);

    if ($company_info) {

        $data['display_name'] = $company_info['display_name'];

        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankss wolfgang1983 and Niranjan N Raju.its working Now feeling glad ..Best wishes