# how to search two or more database tables using mysql like clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function doSearch2 ($string){
        $this->db->like('printer.features', $string);
        $this->db->or_like('printer.model', $string);
         $query = $this->db->get("printer,scanner",12,$this->uri->segment(3));
         return $query->result_array();
    }
```

i am trying to perform a simple search across three tables in one database. I am using codeigniter query builder class. what i want to know is how to use the like clause to search two fields in both tables for a similar string. 
example:

```
searchWord= inkjet;
database= office;
3 tables 
printers
```

scanners
laptops
now how do i search these 3 tables for the searchWord.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you actually using sql server, or mysql?

Comment: i am using mysql sorry

Comment: public function doSearch2 ($string){
            
            $this->db->like('printer.features', $string);
            $this->db->or_like('printer.model', $string);
             $query = $this->db->get("printer,scanner",12,$this->uri->segment(3));
             return $query->result_array();
        }

Comment: Update the question with your code. Maybe this thread will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479079/how-to-join-three-tables-in-codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

you need to join the 3 tables first then do the where or like condition. 
I will not provide a code for you because it will be a good lesson for you 
if you learn from it. Welcome