# how to join tables correctly in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

this is my models

```
function report($where = '')
   {
      $this->db->select(array('o.id_order AS id_order', 'nama_pemesan', 'kota', 'total', 'SUM(biaya) AS do.biaya'));

      $this->db->from('t_order o JOIN t_detail_order do ON (o.id_order = do.id_order)');

      $this->db->where($where);
      $this->db->group_by('o.id_order');

      return $this->db->get();
   }
```

this is my table t_order

[t_order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxhmZ.jpg)

this is my table t_detail_order

[t_detail_order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5NIC.jpg)

this is the error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIGKk.jpg)

this is my controller report

> public function report()
>             {
>                 $this->load->library('form_validation');
>                 $this->cek_login();
>
> ```
>           if ($this->input->post('submit', TRUE) == 'Submit')
>           {
>               $this->form_validation->set_rules('bln', 'Bulan', 'required|numeric');
>               $this->form_validation->set_rules('thn', 'Tahun', 'required|numeric');
>
>               if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
>               {
>                   $bln = $this->input->post('bln', TRUE);
>                   $thn = $this->input->post('thn', TRUE);
>               }
>
>           } else {
>               $bln = date('m');
>               $thn = date('Y');
>           }
>           //YYYY-mm-dd
>           //2017-04-31
>           $awal  = $thn.'-'.$bln.'-01';
>           $akhir = $thn.'-'.$bln.'-31';
>
>           $where = ['tgl_pesan >=' => $awal, 'tgl_pesan <=' => $akhir, 'status_proses' => 'proses', 'selesai'];
>
>           $data['data']   = $this->trans->report($where);
>           $data['bln']    = $bln;
>           $data['thn']    = $thn;
>
>           $this->template->admin('admin/laporan', $data);
>       }
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479079/how-to-join-three-tables-in-codeigniter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to JOIN three tables in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479079/how-to-join-three-tables-in-codeigniter)

Comment: different. in my problem just 2 tables join but 3 column same at both

Answer (score 1):

Join:

```
$this->db->join('t_detail_order do', 'o.id_order = do.id_order');
```

Result:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

CI query builder docs:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your `id_order` in `t_detail_order` to `varchar(15)` . Clear all data and try again

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will help you for sure:-**

```
function report($where = ''){
      $this->db->select(array('o.id_order AS id_order', 'o.nama_pemesan','o.kota', 'o.total', 'SUM(do.biaya) AS biaya'));
      $this->db->from('t_order o');
      $this->db->join('t_detail_order do', 'o.id_order = do.id_order');
      $this->db->where($where);
      $this->db->group_by('o.id_order');
      return $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: send me the tables with data i will give you the exact query

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use Query Builder but this instead.

```
function report($where = '')
{
    $sql = "SELECT o.id_order AS id_order, nama_pemesan, kota, total, 
            SUM(do.biaya) AS biaya
            FROM t_order o 
            JOIN t_detail_order AS do ON (o.id_order=do.id_order) WHERE ? 
            GROUP BY o.id_order";

    return $this->db->query($sql, $where)->get();
}
```

Check htat the return from `report()` is not FALSE which it will be if the query fails. In the controller then

```
$data - $this->model_name->report($some_value);
if($data)
{
   ... do stuff with data
}
else
{
   ... report on, or handle query failure
}
```